gcrd and Associates of an element of the Quaternion algebra over a totally real number field $K$
Let $K$ be a totally real number field of class number 1, and $Q$ the quaternion algebra over the ring of integers of  $K$ with basis
$\{1,i,j,k\}$ such that $i^2 = j^2 = k^2 = -1$ and $ij = -ji, ik = -ki$ and $jk = -kj$.

my first question is does $Q$ has a gcrd algorithm?
where grcd is the greatest common right divisor.
given two associated integral elements $a,b$ , how to find all  $u \in Q$ such that $a=ub$

If so some references would be sufficient for me.

greatest common right divisor

I assume you want to restrict to some order in $Q$, because otherwise everything's a unit.  So you want to know if an order is Euclidean?

yeah thanks I need to know the gcrd algorithm of quaternions with algebraic integers
